# Inconsistencies when using BodePlot with `StateSpaceModel` and `TransferFunctionModel`

Tags: plotting, bugs, control-systems

Consider a linear system .

```
bandPassOL[omega_, k_] := Module[{a, b, c, d},
  a = {{0, -omega}, {omega, 0}};
  b = {{omega*k}, {0}}; 
  c = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
  d = {{0}, {0}};
  StateSpaceModel[{a, b, c, d}]
](*Module*)
osg2SSOL = SystemsModelParallelConnect[bandPassOL[omega1, k1],
   bandPassOL[omega2, k2], All, None];
osg2SSCL = SystemsModelFeedbackConnect[osg2SSOL, {{1, 1}, {3, 1}}];
```

If I want to plot frequency characteristic of such a SIMO system using `BodePlot`

```
BodePlot[osg2SSCL /. {k1 -> 0.5, 
   k2 -> 0.5, omega1 -> 2 Pi 50, omega2 -> 2 Pi 500}, {10^2, 10^4}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   PlotLayout -> "Magnitude"]
```

I get the following, incorrect result.

[image]

If, on the other hand, I wrap the system with `TransferFunctionModel` and send it to `BodePlot`

```
BodePlot[TransferFunctionModel[osg2SSCL, s] /. {k1 -> 0.5, 
   k2 -> 0.5, omega1 -> 2 Pi 50, omega2 -> 2 Pi 500}, {10^2, 10^4}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   PlotLayout -> "Magnitude"]
```

I get the correct result.

If I vary coefficients k1 and k2 from 0.01 to 1, the difference between outputs varies. For small values of k1 and k2, the difference is large and easy to spot, but as k1 and k2 approach 1 the difference gets smaller and easy to miss.

I've tried several other systems and seems that the errors starts to appear only if the system has more than 3 outputs. Though this was far from extensive verification.

Should this be considered a bug?

[image]

The problem persist through the following versions of MMA

> "11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)"
>
> "10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2015)"
>
> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not in `BodePlot`, but in the conversion from `StateSpaceModel` to `TransferFunctionModel`. Compare:

```
TransferFunctionModel[osg2SSCL, s] /. {k1 -> 0.5, k2 -> 0.5, 
omega1 -> 2 Pi 50, omega2 -> 2 Pi 500}
```

[image]

and

```
TransferFunctionModel[osg2SSCL /. {k1 -> 0.5, k2 -> 0.5, omega1 -> 2 Pi 
50, omega2 -> 2 Pi 500}, s]
```

[image]

Adjust the precision for the latter:

```
BodePlot[TransferFunctionModel[SetPrecision[osg2SSCL /. {k1 -> 0.5, 
k2 -> 0.5, omega1 -> 2 Pi 50, omega2 -> 2 Pi 500}, 20], s], {10^2, 10^4}, 
GridLines -> Automatic, PlotLayout -> "Magnitude"]
```

[image]

Comment: This implies that `BodePlot` internally calls `TransferFunctionModel` if the model is in `StateSpace` representation?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: It appears that `SetPrecision` only helps inside `BodePlot` function. If you try to evaluate the following `TransferFunctionModel[SetPrecision[osg2SSCL /. {k1 -> 0.5, k2 -> 0.5, omega1 -> 2 Pi 50, omega2 -> 2 Pi 500}, 20], s]` on its own, wrong result is again obtained. On the other side if you change `Method` to "Inverse" as in `TransferFunctionModel[osg2SSCL /. {k1 -> 0.5, 
k2 -> 0.5, omega1 -> 2 Pi 50, omega2 -> 2 Pi 500}, s, Method->"Inverse"]` the correct result is obtained.

Comment: Increasing the precision makes the result closer, and we cannot tell the difference by looking at the `BodePlot`. If you want to go one step further down the rabbit hole, the hiccup is in `CharactersticPolynomial`. The method "Inverse" does not use `CharactersticPolynomial`, although such a brute approach will choke for larger systems.

Comment: When I evaluate `BodePlot[TransferFunctionModel[SetPrecision[osg2SSCL /. {k1 -> 0.5, 
k2 -> 0.5, omega1 -> 2 Pi 50, omega2 -> 2 Pi 500}, 20], s], {10^2, 10^4}, 
GridLines -> Automatic, PlotLayout -> "Magnitude"]` I still get wrong result. `MMA 11.3 @ Win10`

Comment: What did you then mean by your earlier comment: 'It appears that SetPrecision only helps inside BodePlot function. If you try to evaluate the following TransferFunctionModel[SetPrecision[osg2SSCL /. {k1 -> 0.5, k2 -> 0.5, omega1 -> 2 Pi 50, omega2 -> 2 Pi 500}, 20], s] on its own, wrong result is again obtained.'

Comment: It was working then :) But after your subsequent comment, i tried to change something and now after trying more than 10 times in MMA 11.3 and 10.2 it simply does not work. I tried restarting Kernel, restarting session but just keeps failing. See [this link](https://imgur.com/a/vevpJmh)

Comment: It is possible that the fist time (when I wrote the comment in question) I did not plot correct expression.

Comment: That's possible. Try increasing the precision and see if that helps. As for the original issue, it is known. If you wish you could send a bug report to WRI and when the issue in `CharactesrticPolynomial` is resolved you can be notified.

Answer (score 1):

Replace k1 and k2 with 1/2

```
BodePlot[osg2SSCL /. {k1 -> 1/2, k2 -> 1/2, omega1 -> 2 Pi 50, 
   omega2 -> 2 Pi 500}, {10^2, 10^4}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotLayout -> "Magnitude"]
```

[image]

Comment: O just use `TransferFunctionModel`. The point is, it is most likely a bug and I just wanted to put it out there to get a conformation before submitting bug report to Wolfram Research.

Comment: @ercegovac I'm not able to read thougths :)

Comment: You don't have to, capacity to read written text is sufficient. It says at the end of the question "Should this be considered a bug?"

Comment: Since we are here, did you encounter the same behavior without resorting to rational numbers?